# Specify HTML method in Formtastic action link

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

In a Formtastic `semantic_form_for`, I want the *Cancel* link to point to the destroy action of a controller via the `delete` method:

```
= semantic_form_for @user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f|
    = f.inputs do
        = f.input :password
        = f.input :password_confirmation
    = f.actions do
        = f.action :submit, label: 'Reset password'
        = f.action :cancel, label: 'Cancel password reset',
            as: :link, url: password_reset_path(params[:id]), html: { method: :delete }
```

It is the `html: { method: :delete }` part that I would like to get to work, so that my temporary resource "password reset" is immediately destroyed via `password_resets#destroy` when the user clicks on the *Cancel* link.

Note that this is not about specifying the HTML method for the entire form (as has been asked elsewhere).

The above code ignores the DELETE method, so that I wonder how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `button_html` option.

Try it!

```
<%= f.action :cancel, :label => "Cancelar", url: order_path(@order), button_html: {method: :delete} %>
```